# How to rewrite rule htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need rewrite my url from mydomain.com/index.php/1122 to mydomain.com/1122

I am try with

```
RewriteRule ^register\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /register.php [L]
```

But not working 500 Internal server error

Comment: Check your server logs.

Comment: I see no connection between the task you describe and the rules you post. Either you only told a fraction of what you should have told or you blindly copied some snippet from somewhere without understanding it. About the specific error you receive: the http servers error log file will tell you what the actual issue is. Most likely the rewriting module is not loaded into the http server.